# How to load .web extenstion files in React Native Web with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native-web

In the case of react native web we have a possibility to use files with **.web** and **.android** extensions.
Eg.

```
myFile.web.js
myFile.android.js
```

then we can include them via

```
import myFile from './myFile';
```

and React native web automatically provides proper file content depends on the platform.

It works so far but after I added Typescript the ts compiler started to complain about the missing module **'myFile'** and it's logically okay because we don't have this file and TS compiler doesn't know that the RNWeb will automatically pick a proper file later.
When I disabling Typescript, everything works fine so the system is working. 
The question is how to solve it in the case of Typescript?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where you able to resolve this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Hi @garrettmaring, I provided the answer, please, check it. Unfortunately is a bit hard to format the message in the comments so I create an answer. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found how to avoid this issue is using CommonJS module system - `require`
 instead of ES6 - `import` standard

Example:  `const MyFile = require('./myFile')`

In this case, the TS compiler will ignore it. Unfortunately, it isn't a perfect/right solution as I'd like to see but it works so I just use it as is.

P.S. If someone finds another way, please, provide your solution, I'll be appreciated.